# Solving natural logarithms with absolute value

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, absolute-value

Question from my text: $e^{4x-2014} - 7 = |-3|$. I've never seen this before and my text is useless! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** First of all, what is $|-3|$? Second, sum $7$ on both sides of the equation. Third, apply $\ln$ in both sides of the equation. Fourth: sum $2014$ on both sides of the equation. And finally divide both sides of the equation by $4$. Carry the steps carefully and you'll see what's happening.